# Reach wordpress admin page with another website on

Tags: wordpress, filezilla

I worked on a Website using HTML, CSS, and javascript, and the later is working on the web.

What I seek to do is working on a new version of the website using Wordpress with a template I purchased but at the same time, the old one stays on the time I finish the new one.

[image]

How can I access the /wp-admin page with this path on FileZilla?

Comment: You just need to put WordPress folder inside the www directory and access it by www.yourdomain.com/wordpress. That's it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The wp-admin is folder and in WordPress the same is accessible after authentication by the wp-login.php file in a browser.

In FTP you should access the wp-admin folder and check the index.php file or another file depending on what exactly is your purpose.

If I have understand your question wrong, please provide more information on the same, so I can review it once again.